# Refresh the displayed data from a Dojo Grid

Tags: json, datagrid, dojo

I have a Dojo Grid. Every row has a link to the formular, where the data can be changed. Now, when I click save and close (in the form) I want the grid to reload the displayed data. So far, I've managed to reload the data, but I always jump back to the start of the grid. But, e.g. if I'm at the end of the table, I want to reload just the last few entries.
My grid is connected to a JSONRest Store, so basically I just should know the range which is displayed right now... . How do I get the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem without any put to the store. Here is the code:

```
grid._lastScrollTop=grid.scrollTop;
grid._refresh();
```

And [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/how-to-Refresh-DataGrid-and-scroll-to-old-position-td2026298.html) is the link where I've found the answer. It is the answer number 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you have backed your grid by a store, you simply "put" the changed object to your store. The JsonRest store you are using will send the changes back to your server with a PUT request and the grid will pick up the changes and update the corresponding item.

When pressing save in your form, you would need to create a json representation of your form data (that matches the one used in the grid) and put this to the store:

```
require(["dojo/dom-form", ... ], function(domForm, ...) {
    ...
    var updatedItem = domForm.toObject("yourFormId");
    yourGridStore.put(updatedItem).then(function() {
        console.log("put was successful");
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but it isn't working for me. We change the JS framework right now, and we have started with the lists. So, up until now we don't have any formulars changed, and it won't happen anywhere soon... . So, the formular is opened in a pop-up window, and sends its data to a script on the server. I know, that I could pass some data to the opener, but this won't help because I have no way to tell on which position this particular item is. Or, do I have a way?

Comment: You don't have to deal with positions in the Grid. You just update the store with the changed item.